# Airflow on kubernetes cannot fetch logs

Tags: logging, kubernetes, airflow, kubernetes-pod

My airflow service runs as a kubernetes deployment, and has two containers, one for the `webserver` and one for the `scheduler`.
I'm running a task using a KubernetesPodOperator, with `in_cluster=True` parameters, and it runs well, I can even `kubectl logs pod-name` and all the logs show up.

However, the `airflow-webserver` is unable to fetch the logs:

```
*** Log file does not exist: /tmp/logs/dag_name/task_name/2020-05-19T23:17:33.455051+00:00/1.log
*** Fetching from: http://pod-name-7dffbdf877-6mhrn:8793/log/dag_name/task_name/2020-05-19T23:17:33.455051+00:00/1.log
*** Failed to fetch log file from worker. HTTPConnectionPool(host='pod-name-7dffbdf877-6mhrn', port=8793): Max retries exceeded with url: /log/dag_name/task_name/2020-05-19T23:17:33.455051+00:00/1.log (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7fef6e00df10>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused'))
```

It seems as the pod is unable to connect to the airflow logging service, on port 8793. If I `kubectl exec bash` into the container, I can curl localhost on port 8080, but not on 80 and 8793.

Kubernetes deployment:

```
# Deployment
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: pod-name
  namespace: airflow
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: pod-name
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: pod-name
    spec:
      restartPolicy: Always
      volumes:
        - name: airflow-cfg
          configMap:
            name: airflow.cfg
        - name: dags
          emptyDir: {}
      containers:
      - name: airflow-scheduler
        args:
        - airflow
        - scheduler
        image: registry.personal.io:5000/image/path
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        volumeMounts:
        - name: dags
          mountPath: /airflow_dags
        - name: airflow-cfg
          mountPath: /home/airflow/airflow.cfg
          subPath: airflow.cfg
        env:
        - name: EXECUTOR
          value: Local
        - name: LOAD_EX
          value: "n"
        - name: FORWARDED_ALLOW_IPS
          value: "*"
        ports:
          - containerPort: 8793
          - containerPort: 8080
      - name: airflow-webserver
        args:
        - airflow
        - webserver
        - --pid
        - /tmp/airflow-webserver.pid
        image: registry.personal.io:5000/image/path
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        volumeMounts:
        - name: dags
          mountPath: /airflow_dags
        - name: airflow-cfg
          mountPath: /home/airflow/airflow.cfg
          subPath: airflow.cfg
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8793
        - containerPort: 8080
        env:
        - name: EXECUTOR
          value: Local
        - name: LOAD_EX
          value: "n"
        - name: FORWARDED_ALLOW_IPS
          value: "*"
```

note: If airflow is run in dev environment (locally instead of kubernetes) it all works perfectly.

Comment: You are using `kubectl exec bash` from which pod? Please describe the exact things that you are testing.

Comment: I tried entering the airflow pod, both the webserver and the scheduler containers, and the results are the same.

Comment: Have you used any guide, which you can share? I can try recreating your cluster and deployment. You can also make sure port 8793 is open on both pods.

Comment: The cluster was already configured, however i checked the ports using the command here 

https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/port-forward-access-application-cluster/#creating-redis-deployment-and-service

and both ports 8080 and 8793 were returned, on both containers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was a bug in how the KubernetesPodExecutor from Airflow v1.10.10 tried to launch the pods. Upgrading to Airflow 2.0 solved the issue.

Answer (score 3):

Creating a Persistent Volume and storing logs on them might help.

```
--
kind: PersistentVolume
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: testlog-volume
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  capacity:
    storage: 2Gi
  hostPath:
    path: /opt/airflow/logs/
  storageClassName: standard
---
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: testlog-volume
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 2Gi
  storageClassName: standard
```

if you are using helm chart to deploy airflow, you can use

```
 --set executor=KubernetesExecutor --set logs.persistence.enabled=true --set logs.persistence.existingClaim=testlog-volume
```

Comment: I thought about this, but I was just hoping it would work; it didn't, this helped because if for example you set up S3, it will revert to local logging and then at least you may see what the error is, rather than seeing nothing.

For AWS EKS based clusters, you may need to use `storageClassName: gp2`
You missed a `-` from the top separator.

Answer (score 1):

Airflow deletes the pods after task completion, could it be that the pods are just missing so it can't access their logs?

Try set to see if that's the case
`AIRFLOW__KUBERNETES__DELETE_WORKER_PODS=False`

When running airflow on Kubernetes I suggest using remote logging (e.g. s3) this way the logs are kept when the pods are deleted.

Comment: Thank you for replying! However it did not seem as this is the case, I set the environment var and verified that is in the airflow pod, but the problem persisted. To me it seems like the problem is in the connection between the airflow pod and the created pod, due to it all working fine when the airflow is running locally.

Comment: See here - https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable/airflow#other-configslogging
```For production purposes, you will likely want to persist the logs externally (e.g. S3), which you have to set up yourself through configuration.```

Comment: If the pod fails to start, or doesn't complete the task do the logs still go to S3/GCS or other storage? If the pod fails to start for some reason it would be good if the logs were still recoverable to undersand the issue.

Comment: @alex if the pod fails to start then obviously there will be no pod logs, however, the scheduler logs should indicate that it failed to start the pod.

Answer (score 1):

I have outlined our solution for kubernetes executor logs here (no need for log volumes elasticsearch or any other complex solutions). https://szeevs.medium.com/handling-airflow-logs-with-kubernetes-executor-25c11ea831e4
Our use case may be a little different, but you can adapt for what you need.